# Updating the vertices of a VBO in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

If I want to change the vertices of a VBO, do I have to repeat the process shown in the code below, but with a new vertex array?

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                    vertexBuffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT,
                    vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Or is there a better, more efficient, way? I believe calling the code above every time I want to change the vertices would not be too optimal. I appreciate any answers, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the data of an existing buffer object, then [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) should be used. While [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) creates a new data store for the buffer object, [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml) updates a buffer object's data store. This avoids the cost of reallocating the data store.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification, 2.9. BUFFER OBJECTS, page 24](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> **`BufferData`** deletes any existing data store, and sets the values of the buffer
>   object’s state variables as shown in table ...
>
> .....
>
> To modify some or all of the data contained in a buffer object’s data store, the client may use the command
>
> ```
> void BufferSubData( enum target, intptr offset, sizeiptr size, const void *data );
> ```

Further you should set the `usage` parameter of `glBufferData` for your needs.

See [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification, 2.9. BUFFER OBJECTS, page 23](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf):

> ```
> void BufferData( enum target, sizeiptr size, const void *data, enum usage );
> ```
>
> ....
>
> *`usage`* is specified as one of three enumerated values, indicating the expected application usage pattern of the data store. The values are:
>
> - `STATIC_DRAW` The data store contents will be specified once by the application,
>     and used many times as the source for GL drawing commands.
> - `DYNAMIC_DRAW` The data store contents will be respecified repeatedly by the application, and used many times as the source for GL drawing commands.
> - `STREAM_DRAW` The data store contents will be specified once by the application, and used at most a few times as the source of a GL drawing command.

Comment: ... but beware of updating things which are still in use, or you will get the full copy cost on most drivers, even with `glBufferSubData`. See https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-6-efficiently-updating-dynamic-resources

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you again for a helpful answer. Do you think it is worth creating a VBO if the vertices are going to change frequently? Is there a better way than using VBOs or not?

Comment: @LAD The common and modern way is to use a VBO. But you have to focus on the last parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBufferData.xml), which can be either **`GL_STREAM_DRAW`**, **`GL_STATIC_DRAW`**, or **`GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`**.